# LogShipping and clock change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, log-shipping

I have a log shipping process running. Today I realized that the log files must have been overwritten during the clock change period yesterday, where the clock was set back from 3 AM to 2 AM. So I am concerned that something may be wrong.
I looked at the files that have been backed up and found out they are stored with a filename in UTC time. The period of 01 AM - 02 AM UTC is missing here.

The same output is in log_shipping_monitor_history_detail's output: Here 01AM-02AM are missing as well while the log_time colum is ongoing wihtout any duplicates.

I do backup, copy and restore in 15 minute periods.

The genreal status (master.dbo.sp_help_log_shipping_monitor) of the log shipping process shows 0 (OK).

Does logshipping consider the clock change or do I have to take any actions?

Comment: Log shipping will not be affected by day light saving

Comment: the time change may have caused the first 1am-2am tlog backup file to be over written but as long as that file was already restored to your secondary you should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log shipping restores (like all restores) are based on LSN. Created .trn files should not be affected.   Also, is this for Daylight savings in US, as that is next weekend, not yesterday.  If files have gone missing, there is a different reason for it.  Missing from Primary or Secondary?

Comment: It is in Europe.